# Porcentaje agrupado con totales

Tags: r

Tengo los siguientes datos

```
datos <- read.table(text = '
COL1    COL2    COL3
AA  tipo1   10
AA  tipo2   90
AA  Total   100
BB  tipo1   50
BB  tipo2   100
BB  Total   150
CC  tipo1   1
CC  tipo2   200
CC  Total   201

', header = TRUE, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Datos:

```
COL1    COL2    COL3
AA     tipo1    10
AA     tipo2    90
AA     Total    100
BB     tipo1    50
BB     tipo2    100
BB     Total    150
CC     tipo1    1
CC     tipo2    200
CC     Total    201
```

y quiero sacar el porcentaje de forma que quedaría de la siguiente manera.

```
COL1    COL2    COL3    Porcentaje
AA      tipo1   10      10,0%
AA      tipo2   90      90,0%
AA      Total   100     100,0%
BB      tipo1   50      33,3%
BB      tipo2   100     66,7%
BB      Total   150     100,0%
CC      tipo1   1       0,5%
CC      tipo2   200     99,5%
CC      Total   201     100,0%
```

Habia pensado en algo como esto

```
datos %>%
  group_by(COL1) %>% 
  mutate(porc = COL3 /sum(COL3) )
```

Pero no sé cómo indicarle que el total de la COL2 no lo tenga en cuenta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ya tienes calculado el total de cada grupo, simplemente hay que "colocarlo" en cada fila para que el calculo salga directo. Se me ocurre con una subconsulta para tener solo los totales y luego con un `left_join` la relacionamos con los datos originales:

```
datos %>% 
  left_join(datos %>%
              filter(COL2 == 'Total') %>% 
              select(COL1, COL3),
            by = "COL1",
            suffix = c("", ".y")) %>% 
  mutate(Porcentaje = COL3/COL3.y*100) %>% 
  select(-COL3.y)

  COL1  COL2 COL3  Porcentaje
1   AA tipo1   10  10.0000000
2   AA tipo2   90  90.0000000
3   AA Total  100 100.0000000
4   BB tipo1   50  33.3333333
5   BB tipo2  100  66.6666667
6   BB Total  150 100.0000000
7   CC tipo1    1   0.4975124
8   CC tipo2  200  99.5024876
9   CC Total  201 100.0000000
```